# Travelling to Italy from UK in Coronavirus Times

Tags: uk, schengen, schengen-visas, italy, covid-19

The information available online is murky and often stale. I was wondering if anyone has recently travelled to Italy, and can share their experience of getting in and out.

My Chinese wife has just gotten her EU Spouse Family Visa from the Italy Consulate, plus I'm a British citizen.

My understanding is that Chinese citizens are allowed to travel into Italy, however they haven't been added to the list, as they aren't allowed to fly back home. However, for citizens whom live abroad, this isn't an issue.

From my research, I *think* we don't need to fill in any forms or get a QR code to get into Italy. However, upon returning to the UK, 48 hours before we travel, we both need to fill in a form on the [UK Governments site](https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk), telling them where we travelled.

Have I missed anything? I really would hate to be refused entry, because we missed a form or something.

Comment: Can’t answer your questions, but be aware that the situation changes very often, in many cases with very little or no prior notice, so what is true today may not be true the next day, with the possibility of exclusions or quarantines being added at any time (like the UK did for people returning from Spain for instance).

Comment: Yeah, It's a volatile world! FYI - I think we may just have to fill out [this form](https://www.esteri.it/mae/resource/doc/2020/07/modulo_rientro_da_estero_17_luglio_eng.pdf) to get in. Then fill out the UK form 48 hours before we go home.

Comment: Which region in Italy are you travelling to? Some (e.g. Sardinia) have additional restrictions.

Comment: Venice, Is that okay?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.